# Using `Observable` in place of `$q.all`

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I have an existing Angular 1.6.x project in which I have done something like

```
var defer1 = $q.defer();
        var defer2 = $q.defer();
        $http.get(refTrustUrl).then(function (res) {
            // some code here
            defer1.resolve(true)
        }, function () {
        });
        $http.get(candTrustUrl).then(function (res) {
            // some code here
            defer2.resolve(true)
        }, function () {
        });


        $q.all([defer1.promise, defer2.promise]).then(function () {
            // some code here
        })
```

Now I have to migrate this project to `Angular 4/5`, Is there any work around in `Observable` to match the functionality for `$q.all`.
*Note: I read about `Observable.forkJoin` but didn't got no where*
I did something like:

```
 Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get(refTrustUrl, {responseType: 'text'}),
  this.http.get(candTrustUrl, {responseType: 'text'})
   ).subscribe(
  data=>{
    console.log(data,1)
  }
)
```

but it didn't work. 
Please help thanx...
*I refered this [link](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables) to study about`forkJoin`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be something like this(from the link you provided).

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get(refTrustUrl).map((res:Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get(candTrustUrl).map((res:Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.refTrust = data[0]
    this.candTrust = data[1]
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

Can you try this and se if it works?.

And also you need not subscribe to stream inside like this.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get(refTrustUrl, {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(res => {
```

You should subscribe at the end when you are done with all transformations.